# Inner Product on $\Lambda^n(E)$

Tags: tensors, multilinear-algebra

Let $E$ together with $g$ be a inner product space(over field $\mathbb R$) , $\text{dim}E=n<\infty$ and $\{e_1,\cdots,e_n\}$ is orthonormal basis of $E$ that $\{e^1,\cdots,e^n\}$ is its dual basis. Now we define  $\omega:=e^1\wedge\cdots\wedge e^n$ as element of volume of $E$.

How can I prove that $\omega(u_1,\cdots,u_n)\omega(v_1,\cdots,v_n)=det[g(u_i,v_j)] \qquad \forall u_i,v_j\in E\qquad\text{and } i=1,\cdots,n\ ?$

Of course, I prove that $\omega(u_1,\cdots,u_n)=det[u_1 \cdots u_n]_{n\times n}$ ($u_i$'s are columns of the matrix)but I do not find out how uses it for my problem.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese, if you are in one dimension, what is $e_2$?

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta: Yeah, I realised this seconds later.

Comment: If $\text{dim}E=1$ then $E$ is isomorph with $  \mathbb R$  and $\Lambda^1(E)=E^* $. Hence everything is clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint : (1) Let $$ U=[u_1\cdots u_n],\ V=[v_1\cdots v_n]$$

Then $$ (U^TV)_{ij} = u_i\cdot v_j  =g(u_i,v_j) $$

(2) ${\rm det} (U^TV)={\rm det}\ U {\rm det}\ V$

Comment: It may $g(u_i,v_j)\not = u_i.v_j$  and $u_i,v_i\in E$

Comment: You choose orthonormal basis $\{e_i\}$ wrt $g$. Here in your OP, what is $u_i$ ?

Comment: If $u_i=\sum_k A_i^k e_k,\ v_i=\sum_k B_i^k e_k$, then $$u_i\cdot v_j = \sum_k A_i^kB_j^k= g(u_i,v_j)$$ where $\cdot$ is a matrix multiplication

Comment: I elaborate the previous comment ; Yes $g$ is arbitrary. But we choose an orthonormal basis $\{e_i\}$, where $g(e_i,e_j)=\delta_{ij}$, so that we can represent $u_i$ through a combination

Comment: $$ u_i\cdot v_j = [ A_i^1\cdots A_i^n] [B_j^1\cdots B_j^n]^T= \sum_k A_i^k B_j^k $$ which is clearly $g(u_i,v_j)$

Comment: I prove that you are right. Since $\{e_i\}$ is orthonormal relative to $g$. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The equation you wish to prove is linear in each of the vectors $u_j$ and $v_j$.
Therefore it suffices to show the identity when these vectors are basis vectors.
There are $n$ basis vectors from which we now want to choose the $n$ vectors $u_1,\dots,u_n$.
If we choose any two to be the same, then both sides of the identity vanish (and the identity is true), so we may assume that they are all distinct.
Both sides of the identity change signs in the same way if we permute the vectors $u_1,\dots,u_n$, so way may in fact assume $u_j=e_j$.
Similarly, we may assume $v_j=e_j$.
So it only remains to check this one case, and now the identity is again trivial: both sides equal one.